# Apple app store recent updates not consided as installed

Tags: mac-app-store

I have updated Keynote, Numbers, Pages just now. But these **updates are showing in 'Updates Available' list again.**

Has anyone faced this problem too?  what was the solution?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure they are just not different updates?

Comment: no.. they are same updates.. same date, same size.. no difference at all

Comment: I've seen this too, on two different machines. I seem to recall the problem went away after a reboot (but I still had to let them reinstall once after the reboot).

Comment: You are asking for normal shutdown. Right? I am new to Mac and don't see reboot option

Comment:  menu > Restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the updates as requested and it no more shows those updates. I guess the updates were not installed earlier but some how they were showing installed incorrectly